# Need help on installing rails app on bluehost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bluehost, hostmonster

I am trying to install rails app on bluehost.

I uploaded all my files and installed database, but it shows this error.

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
```

This is the error log
    ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled):
    ...

But all assets are already precompiled.

I really don't know what to do.
Please help me.

Comment: What have you done so far? How have you uploaded the app to the server? Which web server software are you running?

Answer (score 0):

In your rails_root/config/environments/production.rb file
Uncomment (or just change from false to true) this line:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```